# Powershell script to remove group owners as group members Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

I have this script to get all the group owners as members on Azure AD and now I would like to remove them. Could you please guys Help? Thanks

```html
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$resultsarray =@()
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    ForEach ($member in $members){
       $UserObject = new-object PSObject
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -Value $group.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "ObjType" -Value $member.ObjectType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserType" -Value $member.UserType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrinicpalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName
       $resultsarray += $UserObject
    }
}
$resultsarray | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8  -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\scripts\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Yes, we definitely can help if you're stuck with some parts of your code. In that case, please share [mcve] and specify what the issue is.

Comment: I've edited the initial question. Basically I have that script to get all the group owners and then I would like to know how to remove them ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Robert Dyjas , I've edited the initial question. Basically I have that script to get all the group owners and then I would like to know how to remove them ? Thanks a lot for your help –

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your script is to get all group members rather than group owners.

But based on your description, you want to remove all group owners.

I assume you made a typo and your requirement is to remove group owners.

You should use [Get-AzureADGroupOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupowner?view=azureadps-2.0) to get the owners. And then use [Remove-AzureADGroupOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadgroupowner?view=azureadps-2.0) to remove them.

Since `The group must have at least one owner`, you can't remove all the owners. So you need to keep an owner.

The example (I assume that all your groups have the owner `testUpn@tenant.com`. Please modify this script according to your actual situation ):

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true

$keptOwner = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "testUpn@tenant.com"

foreach ($group in $groups){
    $owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    foreach ($owner in $owners){
        if ($keptOwner.ObjectId -ne $owner.ObjectId){
            Remove-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -OwnerId $owner.ObjectId
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to remove all the group members, it doesn't have the limitation.

The example:

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true

foreach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    foreach ($member in $members ){
        Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -MemberId $member.ObjectId
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Basically I have some sites on a csv file and I would like to remove the group owners of these sites and have an output in the end.There are 2 users that are I want to keep on all sites. Could you please help ?

Comment: @PeterSam What result do you want to output? And I have provided the script which can keep a owner. You just need to modify it based on your needs. Please provide more details.